# Is Ito's lemma also valid with stopped integrals?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stopping-times

Consider Ito's lemma in the following standard version
$$h(W_t) = h(W_0) + \int_0^t \nabla h(W_s) dW_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \Delta h(W_s) ds.$$

I am asking myself under which conditions, the deterministic time $t$ can be replaced by $t \wedge \tau$, where $\tau$ is a stopping time. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the same conditions under which the Itô formula is valid. Indeed, the process $X_s = W_{\tau \wedge s}$ is an Itô process with stochastic differential $dX_s = \mathbf{1}_{[0,\tau]}(s) dW_s$ (see e.g. our [book](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Theory+and+Statistical+Applications+of+Stochastic+Processes-p-9781786300508) with Yuliya Mishura, Theorem 8.4). Then, using the Itô formula and this "locality" property once more,
$$
h(X_t) =  h(X_0) + \int_0^t \nabla h(X_s)\mathbf{1}_{[0,\tau]}(s) dW_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \Delta h(X_s) \mathbf{1}_{[0,\tau]}(s)^2 ds \\
= h(W_0) + \int_0^{t \wedge \tau} \nabla h(W_s) dW_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{t \wedge \tau} \Delta h(W_s)  ds.
$$

Answer (score 5):

If (as is customary) the stochastic integral is understood to be continuous in $t$ (a.s.) then the equality holds for all $t$ simultaneously, with probability 1.  As such, $t$ can be replaced throughout by *any* non-negative random variable and the a.s. equality will persist.

Comment: Yes, this is much easier.